# stack and heap in V8 ( JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, v8

does V8 uses stack and heap like the JVM?
if so does it put primitives on the stack and objects on the heap?

Comment: Not making this a full answer since I didn't fully read the article, but there were definitely discussions of stack/heap/register usage in http://wingolog.org/archives/2011/07/05/v8-a-tale-of-two-compilers

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16949690/many-erros-when-i-try-compile-c-in-v8-javascript/19088160#19088160

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, V8 uses a heap similar to JVM and most other languages. This, however, means that local variables (as a general rule) are put on the stack and objects in the heap. This may for instance not hold if a function closes over these values.
As in the JVM, primitives can only be stored on the stack if they are stored in a local variable.

As a user it is not something you would normally need to worry about.

Comment: A lot of the details of the behavior at run time can vary based on the optimizations applied. Cf. http://code.google.com/apis/v8/design.html

Comment: Actually as far as I know the stack vs. heap issue is pretty static in V8, but I am not 100% sure about it. The stuff you link to is about property access in objects which has little to do with this.

Comment: when a function closes over locals the closure object is on the heap? Does the frame never move to the stack when its code is executed?

Comment: yeah I don't understand how closures work with the stack. closures are basically like objects in memory, I don't see how the local variables could be on the stack in the closure...

Comment: An object can be a local variable (your answer implies that objects can't be local), what happens then ? I assume they are still stored in the heap.

Comment: Closed over variables are saved in context objects, of which there is a stack that builds in parallel to the function stack.  And yes, even local objects are heap-allocated.  Anything other than 31/32 bit integers (depending on 32/64 system) is a pointer to a heap-allocated object, due to V8's internal usage of tagged pointers.

Answer (score 40):

- In V8 `null`, `undefined`, `true` and `false` internally are [heap allocated objects](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/c736a452575f406c9a05a8c202b0708cb60d43e5/src/objects.h#L9368). If you are comming from Java you can say that `true` and `false` in V8 are more like `Boolean.TRUE` and `Boolean.FALSE` in Java.
- There is an important difference between *real* local variables and variables that are captured by closures or shadowed by eval/with. Captures variables are stored in a special heap allocated structure called [Context](http://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/contexts.h?r=12394#165) and are accessed indirectly. For more details about *real* vs. context allocates variables see [my answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326300/garbage-collection-with-node-js/5328761#5328761)
- V8 has two compilers: non-optimizing (aka full) and optimizing one:

  - Non-optimizing compiler can't store floating point numbers and integers beyond 31-bit (32-bit on x64) on the stack it always boxes them into [HeapNumber](http://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/objects.h?r=12408#1297)s. It does not try to do register allocation and stores *real* local variables on the stack.
  - Optimizing compiler is much smarter. It does register allocation (linear scan) and can keep full 32-bit integers and floating point numbers on the stack and in the registers (including XMM registers).
- Speaking of JVM: it can perform so called *stack allocation* and allocate a non-escaping object on the stack instead of the heap. A more generic optimization (*scalar replacement*) can sometimes completely eliminate allocation of non-escaping object and explode it into separate fields.

Comment: @Randomblue sorry for the inconvenience! I updated links to use fixed revision numbers to avoid such a problem in the future.

Answer (score -1):

In the most general terms, Yes V8 uses a heap and stack for functioning wherein general local variables are stored in the stack while the objects that need to be maintained are stored in the heap.