# What is better for static messages in Typescript? (performance and memory wise)

Tags: typescript

What is better for static messages in Typescript? (performance and memory wise) 
Variables or methods? Let's say you will need hundreds of them.
**msg1 or msg2()**

```
import {Messages} from './messages';

export class MessagesEN implements Messages {

 readonly msg1 = 'message one';

 msg2(): string {
   return 'hello second!';
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the point of **encapsulation**, your fields (aka `msg1`) must be not visible to the client, you need to let your client to work with your code with methods which manipulate with the data of the objects and change the objects state.

From the point of **performance** accessing the field is a bit faster, because it goes and tries to find the field and returns it. With method it does the same thing and also goes and call it: one extra operation. But in much cases functions that doesn't change it's context, are `inlined`, which allows them to be accessed faster. If you will change something in that function after code execution, the compiler can't not optimize it and it will work slower than field access.

From the point of **memory wise**, method will take more memory from the stack then field

You can see **[jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/312319sakd/2)** that property access is more faster than method access.

Comment: "method will take more memory from the stack then field" --- what this statement is based on? Any standard?

Comment: A memory must be allocated for the method and it's parameters, which is more than a memory for one field, which is in the heap. If you have 2 parameters which are numbers, it will allocate 2x64 bit, which is more than for a field which is 1x64 bit

Comment: Yep, but the "stack". Where did it come from? Memory model of what language defines it? I'm sure JS does not.

Comment: JS also has separated memory model, stack and heap. Refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602864/stack-and-heap-in-v8-javascript. This is implemented in V8

Comment: "JS also has separated memory model, stack and heap" --- JS does not, the standard does not declare notions of stack and heap, like at all. A particular implementation might. My point here is that the question is about *language* and you're making claims that are not applicable to the language.

Comment: Yes, in some cases you are right. But you need an engine to run JS your code and defines it the memory management. Without the engine your specification is only a paper

Answer (score 0):

Performance and memory wise, a variable will always be more efficient than a function as less operations are performed and less is added to the [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack).